# Console application - try catch block doesn't work for Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, console-application

It's probably a basic question but when I try to catch an exception thrown in a `Task` (in a console application) the app breaks with unhandled exception even if I call `task.Wait()` within a try catch block (adding something like `Thread.Sleep` before throwing doesn't help):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() => { throw null; });

    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        if (ae.InnerException is NullReferenceException)
            Console.WriteLine("Null!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Exception!");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: that code is working fine for me.

Comment: This works for me. I get Null! in output.

Comment: You can click on `Continue` button and you will see that the exception will be caught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint in your catch and continue execution you'll see that the exception will be caught.

Comment: but why the error window comes, thats the main problem.

Comment: @Chirag: because `throw null` happens on a different thread where there is no catch block. The debugger cannot predict that you will later catch the exception on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

This screen only shows on the point of the break point what is happening if you continue execution of the program or move the break point further down you will see that the exception is catch and returns Null as expected
And the simplest explanation from debugger point of view will be - I see exception so now what? ooo here is the catch statement lets see what to do with it

Answer (score 0):

If you `await` for your task then you'll have your exception. Otherwise it would be happening in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck this line `Break when this exception type is user-unhandled` and click on continue.

[image]